# Get well-order from total order by choosing finite subsets

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Exercise 7.9 in [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_hlsBpVA3qkC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&source=bl&ots=St5PfKdVk5&sig=q8Tf0xS_r0y989av2LEks3sRw48&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmueH4tKLMAhVC2hoKHYo4DKMQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage):

> Given that any set has a *multiple-choice function*, ie a function picking out a nonempty finite subset of each nonempty subset, show that any totally orderable set can be well-ordered.

To get a well-order we need to modify the total order so that each subset has a least element. For each subset we have a finite subset available, so we can just change the order so that all elements from that finite subset are put below the remaining elements? Does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-empty finite subset of a totally ordered set has a least element. Thus, a multiple-choice function for non-empty subsets of a totally ordered set induces an ordinary choice function, and you can then use the usual argument to get a well-ordering of the set.

Comment: I don't see how this works for the reals R to give us a well-ordering of R

Comment: Why would it not work for $\mathbb R$? A finite set of real numbers indeed has a least element, so given a multiple-choice function we can choose an element from each (possibly infinite) subset and proof the well-ordering theorem. However, we don't know what the well-order looks like for we don't know what the multiple-choice function looks like. (did I get this right? :D)

Comment: @akkarin: You did indeed.

Comment: @user254665: See **akkarin**’s comment just above. We don’t have an explicit multiple-choice function for $\Bbb R$, but if we did, we could use it as described to get an explicit ordinary choice function and then use that to construct a well-ordering of $\Bbb R$.